# Graphics in MXD file are not imported in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-pro

I have an MXD file with some graphics (point and text graphics). When I open the file in ArcMap, the graphics load up correctly. But when I import the MXD file in ArcGIS Pro, the graphics are missing. How do I get them to show in ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: copy and paste from arcmap to arcgis pro.

Comment: @Mapperz That would be fine to do for one file. But we are planning to move from ArcMap to ArcGIS Pro and manually editing each and every file would be inefficient and cumbersome for users.

Comment: bug reports to esri support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. ArcGIS Pro does not support Map annotations/graphics, therefore, these get dropped while importing MXD to ArcGIS Pro.

The solution is to convert the map annotation to features and add them as a layer to the file.
 Refer to this [link](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/page-layouts/converting-graphics-into-features.htm) for the process steps.